Question about Lindelof's theorem proof
For $-1 < r < 1$ we define $\psi_r \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ by
$$ \psi_r(z) = \frac{z+r}{1+rz}. $$


Lemma. If $K$ is a compact subset of $\overline{\mathbb{D}} \setminus \{-1\}$ then $\psi_r \to 1$ uniformly on $K$ as $r \to 1^-$.



Theorem. Supose that $\gamma : [0,1] \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is continuous, $\gamma(t) \in \mathbb{D}$ for $0 \le t < 1$ and $\gamma(1) = 1$. Suppose that $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ is bounded. If $f(\gamma(t)) \to L$ as $t \to 1$, then $\lim_{r \to 1^-} f(r) = L.$


Proof: We can asume $L = 0$ and $|f| < 1$. Let $K = \{z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}} : \Re(z) \ge 0\}$ and fix $\epsilon \in (0,1)$; now choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [0, 1)$ with $|1 - \gamma(t)| < \delta$.  The preceding lemma shows that there exists $R \in (0,1)$ such that $|1-\psi_r(z)| < \delta$ for all $z \in K$ whenever $R < r < 1$. We will show that $R < r < 1$ implies $|f(r)| < \epsilon^\tfrac{1}{6}$; since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\lim\limits_{r \to 1^-} f(r) = 0$, as required. 


Fix $r \in (R,1)$. Let $C_0 = [-i,i] \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$, and let $C_r = \psi_r(C_0)$. Now there exists $t_r \in (0,1)$ such that $\gamma(t_r) \in C_r$ but $\gamma(t) \notin C_r$ for $t_r < t < 1$.

I don't understand last part: Fix $r \in (R,1) [\ldots]$, etc. Can you help me please to understand why there exists such $t_r$? Thanks!

I didn't really answer your question and I can't access the book you mentioned right now so I've decided to remove my answer. Could you update your post with at least the reference so that other users can look into it?
